# Car runs great until shut off then runs bad until shut off again

Tags: dodge, rough-idle, misfire, temperature, avenger

2008 dodge Avenger 3.5L 140,000 miles. Car runs great for however long I’ll run it for, until I shut it off for 5 to 15 minutes after it’s up to temp, then if I start it, it runs like shit, Has a misfire so bad the car shakes, and has no power until I shut it off again. If I’ll let the car cool down for 45 minutes to an hour. She runs great again. Put new plugs in it.

Comment: Have you scanned for OBD codes? If so please edit and add them. If not, getting those codes read is your first step to fixing this issue.